# Как отобразить очень много элементов на странице

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр, google-chrome

Для игры необходимо отобразить на странице очень много элементов, и чтобы браузер не тупил. Он и 500 картинок 100x100 не тянет нормально. Как спецы на картах столько элементов показывают? Куда копать, может в html5 теги специальные есть или скрипты какие-то для оптимизации?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте Ajax и очищайте DOM от ненужных элементов. На картах используют Ajax запросы для определенных участков карты по координатам

Comment: Да это понятно, а что еще есть? Неужели только ajax и больше ничего?

Comment: Производительность браузера напрямую зависит от мощности железа и количества элементов в DOM дереве. Вы хоть бы кусочек кода для примера приводили

Comment: А че тут приводить, 500 элементов отобразил на странице, попробывал ими поманипулировать, и увидел заментые тормоза. Если 1000 картинок, то тормозит жуть как заметно. При этом флешь тянет без проблем. Все вроде говорят что флешь умер, тогда почему html так тупил? Но на флеше делать не хочется, так как он много где не работает. Вот и решил спросить мнение знающих людей.

Comment: Попробуйте canvas. просто только что отрисовал 1000 изображений 425x285 ничего не тормозит. Браузер: Safari 9 ОС: Mac os 10.11

Comment: Попробовал, ужас просто, при перемещении 1000 элементов chrome даже сообщения выбивает с предложением прекратить скрипт, плюс проц просто разрывается.  При попытки перезагрузить страницу, вкладка тупо зависает. В разы выходит хуже чем html простой. Хотя возможно это из-за того что jCanvas лагает так сильно, возможно он написан не оптимально, хотя и сомневаюсь.

Comment: Просто так без понятия что именно вы делаете рассуждать трудно почему подвисает у вас все

Comment: А че там рассуждать, и так понятно что canvas не тянет много элементов. Вот пример  https://jsfiddle.net/dmitriykupriynov/tuenzxw3/ Написан на коленках, но представления о технологии дает. После выполнения в моем браузере он тупо виснет. Если кликаете по окну у вас тоже зависает?

Comment: У меня вообще ничего не виснет в вашем примере. Могу скинуть скрин мониторинга системы если не верите

Comment: Ну на моей ubuntu виснет. Нет, скидывать ничего не надо. Спс.